# Teradata ALTER TABLE to CURRENT taking too long

Tags: teradata

I am running a procedure in Teradata which has the statement "ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME to CURRENT"

It is taking too long to run, I have also collected stats on the given table.
Table size is 130 GB.

Can someone help what can be the issue?

Comment: Stats make no difference in this case. The ALTER has to move rows between partitions. It's AMP-local but still physically moving data around. Probably the only way to make ALTER TO CURRENT faster is to do it more often so there is less data to move. If a large fraction of the data has to move, it can be faster to create a new table and copy the data.

Comment: Can you show the partitioning? TO CURRENT is fast as long as the assignment of a row to a partition is not changed, e.g. `... between trunc(add_months(current_date, -25), 'mon') and last_day(add_months(current_date, +3)) each 1 month` is ok (partition always starts on 1st day of month), but `... between add_months(current_date, -25) and add_months(current_date, +3)) each 1 month` is bad (month starts on the current day of month and will change when the ALTER is not on the same day as the initial partitioning)